# read/write dictionary of strings, integers, and lists of strings from/to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried searching this problem but can only find strings, ints, or lists individually and those solutions seem to clash when I attempt to combine them.

I am writing a program that assigns chores to users taking in account for: user availability, amount they can do in a day, any chores they cannot do, last chore(s) they were assigned, and the previous week of assignments.
I am still working on data structure, but so far it seems like using multiple csv files, lists, and dictionaries is the way to go. I thought about using classes, but I am unsure how to go about that.

I am using a combination of the csv and pandas modules to read/write to files. I have found the csv module (for the most part) writes to the file in the format I want, and the pandas module (again for the most part) reads the files the way I want.

Here is my csv file called users.csv (eventually the LastChore column will be populated by either a single chore, or a list of chores, or maybe I may just remove it and use a different dictionary):

| User | Available | DayMax | Restrict | LastChore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jer | ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'] | 1 | None | None |
| Bob | ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'] | 1 | garbage | None |
| Sara | ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'] | 1 | None | None |
| Kelly | ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'] | 2 | vacuum | None |

Here is the resulting list of dictionaries:

[{'User': 'Jer', 'Available': "['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']", 'DayMax': 1, 'Restrict': 'None', 'LastChore': 'None'}, {'User': 'Bob', 'Available': "['Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']", 'DayMax': 1, 'Restrict': 'garbage', 'LastChore': 'None'}, {'User': 'Sara', 'Available': "['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']", 'DayMax': 1, 'Restrict': 'None', 'LastChore': 'None'}, {'User': 'Kelly', 'Available': "['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']", 'DayMax': 2, 'Restrict': 'vacuum', 'LastChore': 'None'}]

As you can see, my lists are enclosed with "".

**UPDATE:**

I solved the following issue by adding "index=False" to the to_csv line.

```
dataframe.to_csv('users.csv',index=False)
```

I will leave the rest here for anyone else having that problem. I am still having an issue with my lists within the dictionaries having "" around them though.

On top of this, after running the program it keeps adding columns to my file each time I run it.

This is the result of the csv file after running it 4 times:

|  | Unnamed: 0.2 | Unnamed: 0.1 | Unnamed: 0 | User | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Jer | ... |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Bob | ... |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Sara | ... |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | Kelly | ... |

And the resulting dictionaries:

[{'Unnamed: 0.2': 0, 'Unnamed: 0.1': 0, 'Unnamed: 0': 0, 'User': 'Jer',...

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import pandas

#Loading user data from files and creating dictionaries.
def loadUsers():
    try:
        dataframe = pandas.read_csv('users.csv')
        userList = dataframe.to_dict('records')
        dataframe.to_csv('users.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Users database missing. Creating file")
        makeFile("users.csv")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem with files")
    return userList
```

**NOTE:** I have been working with the loadUsers function and editing the csv in excel. Currently I have a makeFile function that creates the csv file with the header row only using csv module, I have yet to write the (newer) code that writes all this information to the csv file. Originally I was using text files, now switching code over to csv files.

Comment: Is this in python? Can you add a tag for it?

Comment: I thought I had, thank you for pointing it out. Done.

Comment: What you need here is a database, not a CSV.  Consider using `sqlite3` to hold your data.  Then, you can make queries and updates in a well-defined way.

Comment: If you want to save and load python objects, you're going to want to `pickle` your data, rather than save it as a CSV. Restructuring your data to work as a database would be a fine way to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my problem by using ast.literal_eval() on each list that was coming out as a string.